# Downloading a large archive from AWS Glacier using Boto

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-glacier

I am trying to download a large archive (~ 1 TB) from Glacier using the Python package, Boto. The current method that I am using looks like this:

```
import os
import boto.glacier
import boto
import time

ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'XXXXX'
SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'XXXXX'
VAULT_NAME = 'XXXXX'
ARCHIVE_ID = 'XXXXX'
OUTPUT = 'XXXXX'

layer2 = boto.connect_glacier(aws_access_key_id = ACCESS_KEY_ID,
                              aws_secret_access_key = SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)

gv = layer2.get_vault(VAULT_NAME)

job = gv.retrieve_archive(ARCHIVE_ID)
job_id = job.id

while not job.completed:
    time.sleep(10)
    job = gv.get_job(job_id)

if job.completed:
    print "Downloading archive"
    job.download_to_file(OUTPUT)
```

The problem is that the job ID expires after 24 hours, which is not enough time to retrieve the entire archive. I will need to break the download into at least 4 pieces. How can I do this and write the output to a single file?

Comment: your download takes longer than 24hrs? I mean, you are limited by bandwidth? On EC2, extract/resend it to S3 so you can download later, or pull it to an EC2 box and download from there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you can simply specify the `chunk_size` parameter when calling `job.download_to_file` like so :

```
if job.completed:
    print "Downloading archive"
    job.download_to_file(OUTPUT, chunk_size=1024*1024)
```

However, if you can't download the all the chunks during the 24 hours I don't think you can choose to download only the one you missed using layer2.

### First method

Using layer1 you can simply use the method [get_job_output](http://docs.pythonboto.org/en/latest/ref/glacier.html#boto.glacier.layer1.Layer1.get_job_output) and specify the byte-range you want to download.

It would look like that :

```
file_size = check_file_size(OUTPUT)

if job.completed:
    print "Downloading archive"
    with open(OUTPUT, 'wb') as output_file:
        i = 0
        while True:
            response = gv.get_job_output(VAULT_NAME, job_id, (file_size + 1024 * 1024 * i, file_size + 1024 * 1024 * (i + 1)))
            output_file.write(response)
            if len(response) < 1024 * 1024:
                break
            i += 1
```

With this script you should be able to rerun the script when it fails and continue to download your archive where you left it.

### Second method

By digging in the boto code I found a "private" method in the Job class that you might also use : [_download_byte_range](https://github.com/boto/boto/blob/develop/boto/glacier/job.py#L162). With this method you can still use layer2.

```
file_size = check_file_size(OUTPUT)

if job.completed:
    print "Downloading archive"
    with open(OUTPUT, 'wb') as output_file:
        i = 0
        while True:
            response = job._download_byte_range(file_size + 1024 * 1024 * i, file_size + 1024 * 1024 * (i + 1)))
            output_file.write(response)
            if len(response) < 1024 * 1024:
                break
            i += 1
```

Comment: I ended up using method 2, which worked well with a few tweaks. I added a conditional that sets the write method to 'ab' if file_size != 0. This way the output gets appended instead of overwritten if it is re-run. Also, the second element of the byte range tuple is off by one (needs a -1). Finally, I added retry exceptions and hash verification as it appears in the _download_to_fileob source code.

Answer (score -1):

You have to add the region_name in your `boto.connect_glacier` function as the following :

```
    layer2 = boto.connect_glacier(aws_access_key_id = ACCESS_KEY_ID,
                                aws_secret_access_key = SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
                                region_name = 'your region name')
```